# React dangerouslySetInnerHTML causes page to scroll to top

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, reactjs

I'm trying to set a toggle state in a react component but every time I click the title the page scrolls up. I tried adding e.preventDefault to the onClick function but it does nothing.

I'm pretty sure it's being caused by the dangerouslySetInnerHTML part of the jsx element.

Is there a way to prevent this behavior or perhaps a better way to do this?

`this.props.page.acf.ios/android` is an html string that is being returned from WordPress JSON api and returns something like the following (using entities.decode to transform any html entities):

```
{
    "ios": "<p>&lt;h1&gt;How it works&lt;\/h1&gt;<\/p>\n<p>Navigation menus are reached from the header by tapping an associated menu icon.<\/p>\n<p>When a user clicks on the hamburger icon in the header, the main navigation menu opens.<\/p>\n<p>The main menu can appear in several states:<\/p>\n<ul>\n<li>Logged Out<\/li>\n<li>Logged In<\/li>\n<\/ul>\n<p>Navigation menu items are displayed with title casing.<\/p>\n<p><img class=\"alignnone size-full wp-image-89\" src=\"http:\/\/mobilestyle.ups.dev\/wp-content\/uploads\/2015\/07\/logged-out.jpg\" alt=\"logged-out\" width=\"292\" height=\"519\" \/><\/p>\n"
}, {
    "android": "<p>&lt;h1&gt;Android stuff&lt;\/h1&gt;<\/p>\n<p><img class=\"alignnone size-full wp-image-89\" src=\"http:\/\/mobilestyle.ups.dev\/wp-content\/uploads\/2015\/07\/logged-out.jpg\" alt=\"logged-out\" width=\"292\" height=\"519\" \/><\/p>\n"
}
```

Here's the component in question:

```
let MobileTabs = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      togglePage: false
    }
  },

  handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      togglePage: !this.state.togglePage
    })
  },

  render() {
    let acf = this.props.page.acf;

    if (this.state.togglePage) {
      return <div className="page__mobile_tabs">
               <h2 onClick={this.handleClick}>Android</h2>

               <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: entities.decode(acf.android)}}></div>
             </div>;

    } else {
      return <div className="page__mobile_tabs">
               <h2 onClick={this.handleClick}>iOS</h2>

               <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: entities.decode(acf.ios)}}></div>
             </div>;
    }
  }
});

module.exports = MobileTabs;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that the scroll is being caused by the dom elements being removed and then added back in. If you add `key` property that lets React know to re-use the dom element instead of removing and adding a new element. In this case, you'd want to use the same key in both the Android and ios cases.

```
return <div key="mobile_tabs" className="page__mobile_tabs">
```

If adding `key` doesn't work, all try adding a `min-height` in `page__mobile_tabs` and see if that helps prevent the scroll. For testing, you could use a large height, like 1500px.

Comment: unfortunately, neither of those suggestions worked :(

Comment: actually I was wrong the min-height solution worked. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried wrapping the `return` data of your `render` function in parens?

javascript will otherwise implicitly insert a semicolon at the end of the line

Comment: hmm, is the state itself actually being toggled?

Comment: Yes. I tried replacing the dangerouslySetInnerHTML divs with divs only containing the text "test " to fill up the page and there is **no** jump in the page scroll.